# AppBundle's Best Practice and how-to go further

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

According to [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html) on the documentation website of [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) they explain how to address your application logic and the best practices. The one thing I am missing in this documentation is the way to store and use your entities. There is a [small section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html#doctrine-mapping-information) that covers the usage of annotations in your entities but we all use that nowadays, I hope you do too.

So far my project has the following entities:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Filename              | Location                          | Type       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Account.php           | src/AppBundle/Entity              | Entity     |
| AccountRepository.php | src/AppBundle/Entity/Repositories | Repository |
| News.php              | src/AppBundle/Entity              | Entity     |
| NewsRepository.php    | src/AppBundle/Entity/Repositories | Repository |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I have trouble creating a Forum.php entity as I need to have 4 database tables:

- forum_sections
- forum_categories
- forum_topics
- forum_posts

Do I need to create 4 entities in one file called Forum.php in `src/AppBundle/Entity` or do I need to do something else to archieve the best practice way of storing and using these entities. It seems that for example `ForumSections.php` and the three other files take a huge amount of space and it is just ugly.

Thank you for reading and thank you in advance for taking the time to leave a reply. I am sorry if there are any spelling errors in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the same strategy as your existing entities, you need to define the four entities in the following files:

```
src/AppBundle/Entity/ForumCategory.php
src/AppBundle/Entity/ForumPost.php
src/AppBundle/Entity/ForumSection.php
src/AppBundle/Entity/ForumTopic.php
```

Then, the namespace of each entity will be `namespace AppBundle\Entity;`

However, when you have several related entities, it's better to create a subdirectory inside the `Entity/` directory. Therefore, you could do the following:

```
src/AppBundle/Entity/Forum/Category.php
src/AppBundle/Entity/Forum/Post.php
src/AppBundle/Entity/Forum/Section.php
src/AppBundle/Entity/Forum/Topic.php
```

Using this layout requires no change in your code. The only thing you should update is the namespace of those entities: `namespace AppBundle\Entity\Forum;`

Comment: This is a great solution. How would I call the Entity in my Controller? The same way I do as `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:News')` but than as `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Forum:Category')`?

Comment: You are right. The short syntax cannot be used with the second strategy that I proposed you earlier. You should use ->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Forum\Category')`. So I think it's better to use the first strategy after all.

Comment: I experienced that myself. You need to whole namespace to get the entity in your controller. The best way is to stick with the first solution as you provided in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to create a new file for each entity. For the entire framework applies that you must write only one class per file and that the filename must match the classname that is in the file (except the extension). What do you mean with a huge amount of space? We are in the year 2015 where computers can handle terabytes :-)